# Will precluding surrogate code points also impede entering Chinese characters?

Tags: unicode, chinese-locale

I have a name input field in an app and would like to prevent users from entering emojis. My idea is to filter for any characters from the general categories "Cs" and "So" in the Unicode specification, as this would prevent the bulk of inappropriate characters but allow most characters for writing natural language.

But after reading the spec, I'm not sure if this would preclude, for example, a Pinyin keyboard from submitting Chinese characters that need supplemental code points. (My understanding is still rough.)

Would excluding surrogates still leave most Chinese users with the characters they need to enter their names, or is the original Unicode space not big enough for that to be a reasonable expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will precluding surrogate code points also impede entering Chinese characters? […] if this would preclude, for example, a Pinyin keyboard from submitting Chinese characters that need supplemental code points.

You cannot intercept how characters are entered, whether via input method editor, copy-paste or dozens of other possibilities. You only get to see a character when it is completed (and an IME's work is done), or depending on the widget toolkit, even only after the text has been submitted. That leaves you with validation. Let's consider a realistic case. From Unihan_Readings.txt 12.0.0 (2018-11-09):

```
U+20009 ‹› (the same as U+4E18 丘) a hill; elder; empty; a name
U+22218 ‹› variant of 鹿 U+9E7F, a deer; surname
U+22489 ‹› a surname
U+224B9 ‹› surname
U+25874 ‹› surname
```

Assume the user enters , then your unnamed – but hopefully Unicode compliant – programming language **must** consider the text on the grapheme level (1 grapheme cluster) or character level (1 character), not the code unit level (surrogate pair 0xD840 0xDC09). That means that it is okay to exclude characters with the `Cs` property.

Comment: In this instance I'm working in Java, so I'll be filtering `char`s using the Character class. So if I'm understanding you correctly: the IME will submit a whole character and what code points it used to get to that character no longer matter to me. The Chinese characters won't be from the `Cs` block.

Comment: I don't know Java, you have to test whether your understanding is correct. Perhaps open a new question and ask how to split into/count grapheme clusters or characters for the string ``. Result should be 5, not 10. BTW code point refers to the (hex) number identifying a character, not the character itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your method would be both ineffective and too excessive.

Not all emoji are outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane (and thus don’t require surrogates in the first place), and not all emoji belong to the general category `So`. Filtering out only these two groups of characters would leave the following emoji intact:

#️⃣ *️⃣ 0️⃣ 1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣ 5️⃣ 6️⃣ 7️⃣ 8️⃣ 9️⃣ ‼️ ⁉️ ℹ️ ↔️ ◼️ ◻️ ◾️ ◽️ ⤴️ ⤵️ 〰️ 〽️

At the same time, this approach would also exclude about 79,000 (and counting) non-emoji characters covering several dozen scripts – many of them historic, but some with active user communities. The majority of all Han (Chinese) characters for instance are encoded outside the BMP. While most of these are of scholarly interest only, you will need to support them regardless *especially* when you are dealing with personal names. You can never know how uncommon your users’ names might be.

This whole ordeal also hinges on the technical details of your app. Removing surrogates would only work if the framework you are using encodes strings in a format that actually employs surrogates (i.e. [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) **and** if your framework is simultaneously not aware of how UTF-16 really works (as Java or JavaScript are, for example). Surrogates are *never* treated as actual characters; they are exceptionally reserved codepoints that exist for the sole purpose of allowing UTF-16 to deal with characters in the higher planes. Other Unicode encodings aren’t even allowed to use them at all.

If your app is written in a language that either uses a different encoding like [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or is smart enough to process surrogates correctly, then removing `Cs` characters on input is never going to have any effect because no individual surrogates are ever being exposed to your program. How these characters are entered by the user does not matter because all your app gets to see is the finished product (the actual character codepoints).

If your goal is to remove **all** emoji and **only** emoji, then you will have to put a lot of effort into designing your code because the Unicode emoji spec is incredibly convoluted. Most emoji nowadays are constructed out of multiple characters, not all of which are categorised as emoji by themselves. There is no easy way to filter out just emoji from a string other than maintaining an explicit list of every single official emoji which would need to be steadily updated.